# Installing CraftQL plugin

Tags: plugin-craftql

I wanted to know if there is any way to install `markhuot/craftql` via the command line.

I tried to follow the one-liner instruction here:
https://github.com/markhuot/craftql#installation

```
composer require markhuot/craftql:^1.0.0
```

but after installing I don't see the options in the backend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to install the plugin with
`./craft install/plugin craftql`. Composer will only download the package and add it to composer.json